# Mousemove not looping on server — but works in jsbin

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, mousemove

This may be a general javascript question, but it's driving me nuts. I have a function that detects pageX and pageY in a mousemove event, and assigns those to a css gradient.

```
$(function(){
    var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        mouseX = e.pageX;
        mouseY = e.pageY; 
    });

    // cache the selector
    var follower = $("#follower");
    var xp = 0, yp = 0;
    var loop = setInterval(function(){
        // change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
        xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12;
        yp += (mouseY - yp) / 12;
        follower.css({
            background : '-webkit-radial-gradient('+xp+' '+yp+', ellipse cover,  rgba(12,47,63,0) 0%,rgba(10,37,49,1) 27%,rgba(5,10,10,1) 100%)'
        });

    }, 30);
});
```

What's really driving me nuts is that it works on jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/owuxep/3/edit

But not on my server (or even the desktop). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[http://paulclarkphoto.com/mouseFollow/``](http://paulclarkphoto.com/mouseFollow/)

Comment: What specifically "doesn't work"?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer The Ghostwriter (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cS_lD9_Ur3g) follows the mouse in the JS Bin example, but not on his server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding 'px' after the values in your css string fixes it for me in Chrome.

```
background: '-webkit-radial-gradient('+xp+'px '+yp+'px, ellipse cover,  rgba(12,47,63,0) 0%,rgba(10,37,49,1) 27%,rgba(5,10,10,1) 100%)'
```

Strange that it works on JS Bin…

Comment: Oh my gosh. So simple Trevor. You're a life saver. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

How do you include the script in your page? It is likely that the '#follower' element is not yet present in the DOM when the javascript is executed. Try including the script after the element is defined, or after the DOM is loaded (i.e using jQuery: `$(document).ready(HERE_SOMEHOW)` )

Comment: The code in the question is in the `document.ready()` function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot find that on the page you have linked to. I find that there is duplicate javascript included inline in the head-element and also in script.js...? But no $(document).ready() anywhere.

Comment: `$(function...)` is the same as `$(document).ready(function...)`

Comment: Wow, how embarrassing, I did not know that. Adding 'px' seems to work though. :)